# Scoped Enums (enum class) relational operators

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class, relational-operators

I've looked all over the place and I can't believe this question has not been asked before.

Is the ordering of scoped enumerators defined by the standard? 
Say if I have the following

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Fruits {Apple, Orange, Tomato};

int main(){

   std::cout << (Fruits::Apple < Fruits::Orange);
   std::cout << (Fruits::Orange > Fruits::Tomato);
   return 0;
}


// output:
// 1 0
```

This outputs 1 0 in g++. But is this standard or compiler specific?

Comment: Almost certain it is standard defined for each unspecified value to be an increment of the previous and starting with 0.

Comment: Are you asking about what order it should produce or about whether or not this should even be a valid expression to compare two scoped enumerators?

Comment: "what order it should produce."

Comment: Values of integer, floating-point, and enumeration types can be converted by static_cast or explicit cast, to any enumeration type. If the underlying type is not fixed, the result is unspecified (until C++17)undefined behavior (since C++17)   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum  It looks like while it's unspecified, it generally works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the picture and confirm that yes, the ordering is defined. We start with why one may put two enumerators in a relational expression...

> **[expr.rel]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.rel#2) The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on operands of
>   arithmetic or enumeration type...
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.rel#5) If both operands (after conversions) are of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type, each of the operators shall yield true if the
>   specified relationship is true and false if it is false.

... where the usual arithmetic conversion for a scoped enumeration is a no-op...

> **[expr]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#9) Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of scoped enumeration type ([dcl.enum]), no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same
>     type, the expression is ill-formed.

So they *do not* convert, and may only be compared to an object of the same exact type. The values given to the enumerators (as specified by the other answer) are what determines if *"each of the operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and false if it is false"*. That's how the comparison is done.

It's also worth noting that enumeration type variables can take values that are not enumerated! So for instance...

```
enum class foo {
  min, max = 10
};

foo mid = static_cast<foo>(5);
```

... is valid, and the comparison `mid > foo::min` will hold just the same, because the preceding paragraph is generalized to include more than just the named values.

Comment: Interesting and clear. Cppreference should be clearer on this point.

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of the values is specified in [[dcl.enum] point 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#2):

> If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the
>   corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an
>   initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the
>   value of the previous enumerator by one.

Therefore the values of `Fruits` are `0, 1, 2` respectively and since comparisons on enums are little more than type safe integer operations it behaves as you see.

Comment: I knew that was the case for unscoped enums, but I wasn't sure that the standard guarantees the same for scoped enums as well. Thanks for the reference.